# How to make a Kotlin generic method static?

Tags: generics, kotlin, static

I know that it is possible to write a static generic method in Java.

I tried to implement my own solution in Kotlin but I failed.

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    companion object <T> // error: Type parameters are not allowed for objects.
    {
        private var value: T? = null

        // implement some methods
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to implement a static generic method in Kotlin?

Comment: Having `private var value: T?` in the companion object would be the same as having `private static final T value;` in Java. That doesn't work in either of the languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`companion object` is not method. It's, in fact, an `object` that is companion to the `Wrapper` class, therefore it cannot be aware of the generic type of parent class.
Same thing applies to Java:

```java
public class Wrapper<T> {
    public static T value; //ERROR
}
```

Within this `companion object` you can declare methods and fields that will be `static` in java world.

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    companion object
    {
        fun <T> genericMethod(){

        }
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that type of `Wrapper<T>` is not connected with type `T` in `fun <T> genericMethod()`.

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin, there's no difference between static (top-level, companion) and instance functions/methods. So, the same generic function/method

```
fun <T> something() {
    // TODO
}
```

is valid both within a class body, on top-level, and in companion or object declaration.

Answer (score 1):

### Companion object is a singleton

Generic type parameters of the class are not allowed inside the companion objects. The reason for this is that a single `companion object` is shared across all the instances of that class. This is true also for the different parameterized types of the same class. So, for example, the `companion object` is the same for whether it is a `Wrapper<String>` or a `Wrapper<Int>`. In other words, the `T` of the enclosing class cannot take different forms `String` or `Int` inside the `companion object`.

The type parameters can only be used with the member functions and member properties of the class. The `value` property in your example is not the member of the `Wrapper` class, it is a member of the `companion object`.

This is the same thing as saying:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    class SomeOtherClass<T> {
        private var value: T? = null
        // implement some methods
    }
}
```

The difference is just a single object vs multiple objects of `SomeOtherClass`. The `T`s are independent for `Wrapper` and `SomeOtherClass`.

---

That's it! Hope that points you in the right direction for the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the generic type parameter of the function. It doesn't matter where the function is, be it a class, a file, a companion object, etc.
Example with companion object:

```
companion object {
    fun <T> generic(t: T) {
        // do something generic
    }
}
```